# unable to decrypt md5-rc4 with key

Tags: java, cryptography

below algo is followed to encrypt can we decrypt it back , please help.:

1. Create the MD5 hash of the key (key hash) as described in RFC 1321.
2. Encrypt the source header value string using the MD5 key hash as the cipher for the RC4 encryption algorithm.
3. Encode the encrypted text in Base64 as described in RFC 3548 to get the final header value.
4. The final inserted Xheader will be X-amobee: `base64( RC4( MD5(key), MSISDN ) )`.

Comment: Can you provide an example, perhaps an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) ?

Comment: Is there an IV somewhere or are keys single use? Otherwise this is about as strong as ROT13.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get what's the problem here.

You have to convert your final header in `base16` and then decrypt it using the `RC4` algorithm with the same key `MD5(key)`.